# Wake up heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, heroku, dyno

So, my heroku NODE.js app has always been functioning and I was trying it out today again via my url but for some reason it gives me an application error message.

I read about and logged in to my dashboard and it says that the app is asleep..
I have the free tier of heroku and I understand that the app has to sleep 6 hours in a day(correct?)
Is there a way to wake up my app? (NOT KEEP IT ALIVE As I have read in other posts, JUST wake it up)

Follow up: Is there a way to know how much time I still have left before it wakes up?(Because of the necessary 6 hours of sleep of the free heroic tier)

Comment: If your app is asleep and still has available dyno time, it will be woken up (it won't show an application error). If you see an app error and restarting the app fixes it, that means your app has a bug and you should run `heroku logs --tail`

Comment: What do you mean by available dyno time? Where can i see that? @hunterloftis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out and RESTARTED the dynos by going in to the dashboard.

I went to personal apps, then clicked my app and was in the dashboard for the specific app.

On the top right corner I saw like a sidebar(3 vertical dots)

I clicked and hit restart dynos. That automatically restarted my app and woke up.

[image: Restart all dynos]