# heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143

Tags: heroku, offline, heroku-cli

Currently seeing the following in the heroku logs for the deployed herokuapp.com

2021-07-18T14:29:18.171160+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling

2021-07-18T14:29:18.173322+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down

2021-07-18T14:29:19.882314+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM

2021-07-18T14:29:20.066472+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143

kapturebyslick.com and the underlying kapturebyslick.herokuapp.com have been going online and offline for the last 10 hours.

Successfully deployed app through Github workflow and saw URLs behaving as expected in Firefox and Chrome initally however over next 10 hours site keeps going offline and periodically coming online.

React ap with Node.js
Development sqlite3 dB & Production posture dB

Comment: This link resolved the issue for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748739/wake-up-heroku-app

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a free Heroku account, there is very little free dyno time. Which means if your app doesn't receive any requests for ≈ 30 mins, your app going to sleep it will wake up again when it receives request.

You can use 'Heroku pinger' to keep your app up, but there is a con: Heroku gives only 1000 free dyno hours per month per account with verified credit (450 hours only for account without credit verification),Your app will inevitably go to sleep if your account exceeds this limit.

Refer:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours

*Hopefully this might help you* :D

> Note: I'm a beginner, so if there are any mistakes, please excuse me

Answer (score 0):

Believe this is related to Github Actions workflow not deploying with PGSSLMODE=no-verify.  Deploying through heroku-cli with this config set results in successful deploy and app rendering as expected in Firefox and Chrome.